# AMD Radeon RX6800 XT does not detect monitor on second Display Port

Tags: graphics, display, multiple-monitors

I have a brand new AMD Radeon RX6800 XT graphic card.
It has three connectors: 2x Display Port and 1x HDMI.
I have two HDMI monitors.
In both Windows 11 Pro and Ubuntu 22.10 the behavior is the same:

- if I connect both monitors with two DisplayPort > HDMI cables, only one is detect
- no matter if I swap the cables (and connectors) always the **same** monitor works (and I cannot understand how is it possible!)
- in this situation, neither Ubuntu nor Windows find the other screen
- but if I use one DisplayPort and one HDMI output both monitors are detected by both OSs

I'm aware I can just live with this workaround, but I'd like to understand if it's an expected behavior or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My cousin had the same issue and we tried previous version of drivers as it is described in other comments. But there was no effect. Than I've installed the latest version of drivers and AMD Adrenalin back and tried there every setting that seemed suitable for the situation.

Finally helped: to make Quick setup for AMD Eyefinity then to make Discard. As I've understood - possible cause is that by some reason AMD Eyefinity setting stuck in "One Display mode" without any respective indication. So, it was needed to on/off this setting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).